# Problem with passing struct pointer by pthread_create

Tags: c, pthreads

In the code below, when I print `f->msg` in the main function, the data prints out correctly. However, if I pass the mystruct *f in `pthread_create` and try to print out the msg value, I get a segmentation fault on the second line of the `receive_data` function.

```
typedef struct _mystruct{
    char *msg;
} mystruct;

void *receive_data(void* vptr){
    mystruct *f = (mystruct*)vptr;
    printf("string is %s\n",mystruct->msg);
    return NULL;
}

int main(){
    mystruct *f = malloc(sizeof(mystruct));
    f->msg = malloc(1000);
    f->msg[0] = '\0';
    strcpy(f->msg,"Hello World");
    pthread_t worker;
    printf("[%s]\n",f->msg);
    // attr initialization is not shown
    pthread_create(&worker,&attr,receive_data,&f);
}
```

Other initialization code for pthread is not shown.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: `f->msg[0] = '\0';` is completely useless in that code of yours

Comment: Yeah, I see that, in the actual code, I do strcat instead of strcpy which needs to locate '\0'. But, it was my mistake in this context.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're passing a pointer-to pointer-to `mystruct`. Don't do that.

```
pthread_create(&worker, &attr, receive_data, f);
```

is enough. `f` is already of type `mystruct*`. `&f` is of type `mystruct**`.

Comment: Also OP's program almost surely terminates before it has a chance to print anything since it runs off the end of `main`...